# React native sync-storage vs AsyncStorage

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I'm still fresh with React Native. Stumbled upon some projects that uses sync-storage and AsyncStorage. Is there any difference between these 2 storage packages, base on scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of the sync-storage package but after looking into it, I can see that it relies on the deprecated package for async storage. Anyone who has been using async storage recently in react-native will point you towards the most up to date library: [@react-native-async-storage/async-storage](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage).